# How to combine django crispy form layout and quill JS?

Tags: django-models, django-forms, quill

I am trying to combine crispy form layout with quill js that I am using for my description field but in the dev tools it does render the quill classes and stuff but the problem is, it is not showing on the page itself. I want to add the safe filter(guess that's what is missing to it) but I don't know how. I looked at the documentation but found no answer to that particular issue.

```
class CreateProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = "__all__"

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(CreateProjectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       self.helper = FormHelper()
       self.helper.layout = Layout()
```

Not using any layout for now.

```
class Project(models.Model):
    typeChoices = (
        ("Software Development", "Software Development"),
        ("Task Management", "Task Management"),
        ("Business Management", "Business Management"),
   )
   
   project_type = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=typeChoices)
   slug = models.SlugField(max_length=30)
   key = models.CharField(max_length=7, unique=True)
   project_description = QuillField(blank=True, null=True)


   def __str__(self):
       return self.project_name
```

I want to have something like this {{description|safe}} in the description field itself. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks